# Get data without appends and relations in Laravel from Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have model `Project` which has some `$appends` and some relations like `pages`, `brands`, `status` etc.

And in `$appends` it has `pages`, and in `Page` model it has lot of other `$appends`. Now while I do `Project::find($id)` it retrieves project, it's pages and other models which belongs to Page. 
And I havn't done `with`, so for each page it fires lots of queries.

Without using

```
DB::table('projects')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Is there any better approach to load only Project model, no relation, no appends, nothing via Eloquent ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately thats not how it works. If you want to **remove** the appends you could do so as follows:

```
$project = Project::find(1);
$project->setAppends([]);

return $project; //no values will be appended
```

However if those appends are doing database calls and you prefer not to you should rexamine whether or not it makes sense for the appends to be there. It's really a matter of whether you think it makes sense for the `appends` to **always** be included or not.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I just fixed that with `return $this->respond(Project::find($Id)->setAppends([]));`;

Comment: I tried this in my model but didn't worked, Don't know why. http://prntscr.com/h7t9nt

Comment: as in, it still made the queries?

Comment: Yes. And it appends every keys also

Comment: I'm not sure it works as a scope, but really the second half of my comment is worth exploring.

Comment: Got it. I think I have to make it optional rather than in appends.

Comment: you save my life bro. this is strange. how can I learn these methods? I decided to create a new model connected to that table, that's a bad decision. With your solution, my project will be clean. thank you

Comment: and same for

    $project->setRelations([]);

Answer (score 17):

It was usefull for me:

```
$services = Service::all()->makeHidden(['appendField1', 'appendField2'])->toArray();
```

Answer (score 14):

```php
// YourModel.php

public static $withoutAppends = false;

public function scopeWithoutAppends($query)
{
    self::$withoutAppends = true;

    return $query;
}

protected function getArrayableAppends()
{
    if (self::$withoutAppends){
        return [];
    }

    return parent::getArrayableAppends();
}
```

```php
$result = YourModel::withoutAppends()->all();
```

Comment: works one caveat is it doesn't work for models called through relationships, just top level.

Comment: You should make sure to reset property `$withoutAppends` to `false`, otherwise any successive queries will be without the appends :|

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with the **append** fields of the second model i was trying to access, it was going into an infinite loop.
So in User Model;

Instead of

```
return $this->organisation->is_enabled;
```

using:

```
return $this->organisation->setAppends([])->is_enabled;
```

Solved the problem for me since setAppends([]) function is unappending the unnecessary relations

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
User::where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->makeHidden(['full_name','start_end_date']);
```

Comment: this will anyway fire all queries to db, Question is more focused on lot of queries, not just making properties hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it works for collection containing multiple records. But If you need it for a single model without relations, you can just

```
$project->attributesToArray();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
->makeHidden(['usages'])
```

option can help you. To ignore other relations, `YouModel::setEagerLoads([])`
cab help you.

Remember that, you have to use makeHidden as Statically. For example,

```
ScientistModel::where('name','Aziz Sancar')->first()->makeHidden(['appendsName']);
```